# Python and django: how to set a filter value with a form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have created the following model that give me the possibility to get all daily income:

```
class Ricavi(models.Model):
    quantita=models.DecimalField()
    data_contabile=models.DateField()
```

After that I have created a views.py that give me the possibility to collect my data in yearly and monthly view as following:

```
 ricavi = dict()
        total_ricavi=dict()
            for year, month, totale in(Ricavi.objects.values_list( 'data_contabile__year', 'data_contabile__month').
                annotate(totale=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('quantita') * F('ricavo')*(1+F('iva'))),
                output_field=FloatField())).values_list('data_contabile__year', 'data_contabile__month', 'totale')).filter(data_contabile__year=2019):
                if id not in ricavi.keys() :
                    ricavi[id]=list(defaults)
                index=month-1
                ricavi[id][index]=totale

            total_ricavi={'Ricavi Lordi': [sum(t) for t in zip(*ricavi.values())],}
```

Now I have fixed the `data_contabile__year` equal to 2019 ad example. But I want to have the possibility to choose the year (ad example using a selection form). How could I get this result?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example:

form.py:

```
from django.forms import IntegerField

class RicaviForm(Form):
    Year = IntegerField(label='Year')
```

view.py:

```
def ricavi_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RicaviForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           # Do somthing  with form['Year'].value()
            return redirect('stack:ricavi_view')
        else:
            errors = form.errors
            form = RicaviForm()
            context = {'form': form, 'ERROR': errors}
            return render(request, "stack/ricavi.html", context)
    else:
        form = RicaviForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, "stack/ricavi.html", context)
```

ricavi.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="{% url 'stack:ricavi_view' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" onclick="submit()">submit</button>
     </form>
{{ERROR}}
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'stack'

urlpatterns = [
    path('ricavi', views.ricavi_view, name='ricavi_view'),
]
```